# Strapi SMTP setup

Tags: smtp, strapi

How should I connect to a local smtp server using Strapi? I need it to send reset password email to user email. I've managed to do it with sendgrid, by installing providers

```
npm install strapi-provider-email-sendgrid@alpha --save
```

however, I'm not sure how to do it with our own smtp server.

For example I have this SMTP server details, however I don't know where should I plugin these values to:

1) SMTP server address: 10.10.10.9

2) port: 25

3) Username: username

4) Password: password

Accoding to [nodemailer link](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/), I can set it here. However, I still don't know where to set it in strapi

```
let smtpConfig = {
    host: 'smtp.example.com', // 10.10.10.9
    port: 587, // 25
    secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
    auth: {
        user: 'username', // username
        pass: 'password' // password
    }
};
```

How can I duplicate the sendgrid provider and modify it?

There's only "Sendmail Default From" and "Sendmail Default Reply-To" fields in the email setting page:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For you need you are not using the correct Strapi email provider.

Please check `strapi-email-nodemailer` you will have all options you need.

`npm i strapi-email-nodemailer --save` there is no tag `alpha` for this provider.